# How distribute several application as one archive/bundle/app for mac os x

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to distribute two application at the same time, for example, menu bar additions and full fledged app in mac. What's options do I have ? Is it possible to distribute such "bundle" in Mac App Store ?

Comment: I think it'll be helpful if you include more info about your app, for example, what they do.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have to run the second application manually, or not via your main application, then it's possible.

You can put it somewhere in the main application bundle for example : (Contents/Executables). If you are using Xcode, you can do so by adding a copy file build phase to your main application bundle.

Just make sure you code-sign every bundle, as the code-signing the main application bundle is not not enough.